# Synapse - can I go to the location of a search result?

Tags: xfce, thunar, synapse

When a search result (say a file or folder) in Synapse is displayed, can I somehow enable to go said result's location in my file manager? (I suppose it's Thunar since I use Xubuntu 13.10)

Comment: Not really sure but last time I used synapse you could use the Tab key to select "open with".

Comment: Oh you're right. That's good enough for the time being. Please submit your comment as reply so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: I haven't used it in three years :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure but last time I used synapse you could use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to select "open with"

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes you can, tab and scroll down a bit:

[image]